# New window not opening when method called

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a program in Java that will open a new window when a button is clicked. I've used an actionlistener and actioncommand to call a method that initializes another JFrame when called. However, when I click the button(and therefore my method is called), nothing happens. I'm using IntelliJ community edition and the code compiles fine.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JFrame frame2;
    JPanel panel;
    JPanel panel2;
    JLabel label1;
    JLabel label2;
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;
    JButton button3;
    JButton button4;
    int window;
    String newlabel;

    public enum Actions {
        BUTTON1,
        BUTTON2,
        BUTTON3,
        BUTTON4
    }

    public GUI() {

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(190, 125);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(190,125);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.setLayout(null);

        label1 = new JLabel("The C Family");
        label1.setBounds(50,5,200,25);
        panel.add(label1);

        button1 = new JButton("C");
        button1.setBounds(10,30,80,25);
        button1.setActionCommand(Actions.BUTTON1.name());
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button1);

        button2 = new JButton("C#");
        button2.setBounds(100,30,80,25);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        button2.setActionCommand(Actions.BUTTON2.name());
        panel.add(button2);

        button3 = new JButton("C++");
        button3.setBounds(10,60,80,25);
        button3.addActionListener(this);
        button3.setActionCommand(Actions.BUTTON3.name());
        panel.add(button3);

        button4 = new JButton("Rust");
        button4.setBounds(100,60,80,25);
        button4.addActionListener(this);
        button4.setActionCommand(Actions.BUTTON4.name());
        panel.add(button4);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals(Actions.BUTTON1.name())) {
            window = 1;
            newWindow();
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(Actions.BUTTON2.name())) {
            window = 2;
            newWindow();
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(Actions.BUTTON3.name())) {
            window = 3;
            newWindow();
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(Actions.BUTTON4.name())) {
            window = 4;
            newWindow();
        }
    }

    public void newWindow() {

        if(window == 1) {
            newlabel = "C";
        } else if (window == 2) {
            newlabel = "C#";
        } else if (window == 3) {
            newlabel = "C++";
        } else if (window == 4) {
            newlabel = "Rust";
        }
        
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setSize(500,500);

        frame2 = new JFrame();
        frame2.setSize(500,500);
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.add(panel);

        panel2.setLayout(null);

        label2 = new JLabel(newlabel);
        label2.setBounds(105,20,200,25);
        panel2.add(label2);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`frame.setVisible(true);` -> `frame2.setVisible(true);`